# Access instantiated class methods

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently working on a class that manages the user "authorization", and since the users are stored on a database, i need to access it from within the class. I've found this Mysql class: http://github.com/JeffreyWay/PHP-MySQL-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqlDb.php

But when i have instantiated the Mysql class with the mysql login information. How can i then use the methods from the Mysql class inside the other class?

Comment: I think what you are talking about is [extending](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) the MysqlDb class with your class?

Comment: I think not. Because i want to include the earlier instantiated mysql connection options .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a reference to the MySQL object in your class.

I recommend passing the MySQL object into your constructor and accessing it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $mysql;

    function __construct($mysql)
    {
        $this->mysql = $mysql;
    }

    function foo()
    {
        $this->mysql->doSomething();
    }
}
```

You can then create your instance of the object with:

```
$myobject = new MyClass($mysql);
```

Comment: That looks correct, if you run `SELECT * FROM users` on your database manually do you get any results?

Comment: Ups embarrassing.. I selected the wrong table.. Thanks for you help! :D

Answer (score 0):

In your other class you should requir Mysql class file. Create an ocject. And you can use public methods of `Mysql` class.

```
require 'path/Mysql.php';
$mysql = new Mysql();

$mysql->connect();
```

But check if Mysql class methods ere public.
If there are static methods - use `::` instead of `->`.

You can do create `__autoload` function and don't require Mysql class.